# Creating executable for Python 2.7, getting RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, runtime-error, py2exe

I am running Python 2.7. I downloaded py2exe version 0.6.9 win32 to create an executable out of my .py file. I know it is an older version so I'm not sure if that's what's creating the error.

I have gone through the steps: creating a setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=["MyFileName.py"])
```

Then running `python setup.py py2exe --help` from the command window, then `python setup.py py2exe`

However, it turns up a

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object.
```

I understand that this happens when the code encounters infinite recursions, but my .py file does not have this error so I'm not sure where it's coming from. I tried adding

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
```

based on another StackOverflow answer but am still getting the same error.

I am happy to provide pertinent information to help troubleshoot, but I'm not sure what would be helpful. Would using another tool other than py2exe like PyInstaller or cxfreeze be better or is it likely to run into the same error?

EDIT:

Here is the traceback, I can't seem to get it from the beginning, but here is what is showing on my command prompt.

```
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 423, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 332, in _safe_import_h
ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 137, in import_hook
    m = self.load_tail(q, tail)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 214, in load_tail
    m = self.import_module(head, mname, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
    r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 314, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 423, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 332, in _safe_import_h
ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 137, in import_hook
    m = self.load_tail(q, tail)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 214, in load_tail
    m = self.import_module(head, mname, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
    r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 314, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 423, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 332, in _safe_import_h
ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 137, in import_hook
    m = self.load_tail(q, tail)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 214, in load_tail
    m = self.import_module(head, mname, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
    r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 314, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 456, in scan_code
    self.scan_code(c, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 423, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 332, in _safe_import_h
ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 137, in import_hook
    m = self.load_tail(q, tail)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 214, in load_tail
    m = self.import_module(head, mname, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
    r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 314, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 456, in scan_code
    self.scan_code(c, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 456, in scan_code
    self.scan_code(c, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 423, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 343, in _safe_import_h
ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, [sub], level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 141, in import_hook
    self.ensure_fromlist(m, fromlist)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 231, in ensure_fromlis
t
    submod = self.import_module(sub, subname, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
    r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 295, in load_module
    m = self.load_package(fqname, pathname)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 471, in load_package
    self.load_module(fqname, fp, buf, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 314, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 446, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 332, in _safe_import_h
ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 136, in import_hook
    q, tail = self.find_head_package(parent, name)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 192, in find_head_pack
age
    q = self.import_module(head, qname, parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
    r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 314, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 423, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 332, in _safe_import_h
ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 137, in import_hook
    m = self.load_tail(q, tail)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 214, in load_tail
    m = self.import_module(head, mname, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
    r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 314, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 456, in scan_code
    self.scan_code(c, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 423, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 332, in _safe_import_h
ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 137, in import_hook
    m = self.load_tail(q, tail)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 214, in load_tail
    m = self.import_module(head, mname, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
    r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 295, in load_module
    m = self.load_package(fqname, pathname)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 471, in load_package
    self.load_module(fqname, fp, buf, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 314, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 449, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(parent.__name__, None, fromlist, level=0)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 343, in _safe_import_h
ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, [sub], level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 141, in import_hook
    self.ensure_fromlist(m, fromlist)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 231, in ensure_fromlis
t
    submod = self.import_module(sub, subname, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
    r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 295, in load_module
    m = self.load_package(fqname, pathname)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 471, in load_package
    self.load_module(fqname, fp, buf, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 314, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 423, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 332, in _safe_import_h
ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 137, in import_hook
    m = self.load_tail(q, tail)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 214, in load_tail
    m = self.import_module(head, mname, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
    r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 314, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 456, in scan_code
    self.scan_code(c, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 423, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 332, in _safe_import_h
ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 136, in import_hook
    q, tail = self.find_head_package(parent, name)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 199, in find_head_pack
age
    q = self.import_module(head, qname, parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
    r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 295, in load_module
    m = self.load_package(fqname, pathname)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 471, in load_package
    self.load_module(fqname, fp, buf, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 314, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 423, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 343, in _safe_import_h
ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, [sub], level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 141, in import_hook
    self.ensure_fromlist(m, fromlist)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 231, in ensure_fromlis
t
    submod = self.import_module(sub, subname, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
    r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 295, in load_module
    m = self.load_package(fqname, pathname)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 471, in load_package
    self.load_module(fqname, fp, buf, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 314, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 423, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 332, in _safe_import_h
ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 137, in import_hook
    m = self.load_tail(q, tail)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 214, in load_tail
    m = self.import_module(head, mname, m)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
    r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
    r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 295, in load_module
    m = self.load_package(fqname, pathname)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 463, in load_package
    m = self.add_module(fqname)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 478, in add_module
    self.modules[fqname] = m = Module(fqname)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

If I try to run it using Pyinstaller I get the error `TypeError: iteration over non-sequence` which seems like it relates to the same thing that is wrong using py2exe.

in MyFileName.py I import the following modules:

```
import __future__    
#from __future__ import division
import itertools
from Tkinter import *
import numpy as np
from collections import OrderedDict
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource, figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
import pandas as pd
import datetime as datetime
import pandas.util.testing as tm; tm.N = 3
import pyodbc
import csv
from bokeh.charts import Bar
from bokeh.palettes import RdYlGn11
import calendar
import dateutil
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback!

Comment: @KlausD. I added the error traceback! For some reason it cut off the beginning of it in my cmd window, not sure how to get that. Hopefully this is enough?

Comment: To get more console output in windows, right click your CMD window, click properties, click layout, and then finally change screen buffer height to something big (i have mine set to 3000). 
Also, can you add more of your "myfilename.py". I would like to see what you import in there

Comment: @Gamrix, I changed the screen buffer height but it's still only showing the amount of traceback as I provided before, and a whole lot of blank space _below_ the end of it... Not sure how to get the full traceback still. I added the imports of myfilename.py! Hope that is helpful and let me know if there is another way to get the full traceback.